# How to back up SQL Server database via Winforms C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-backups

I'm stuck on a issue where I need to backup my database via Winforms. I managed to find a sample SQL code in order to achieve this task.

My query here :

```
SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBS\\DB;Initial Catalog=" + metroTextBox1.Text + ";Integrated Security=True");

Sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + metroComboBox1.Text + " TO DISK = '" + metroTextBox4.Text + "\\" + metroComboBox1.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak'";
```

I have no idea how to proceed next. What should I use in this scenario? (`ExecuteScalar`, `ExecuteNonQuery`..etc)

Any help would be appreciated.

Note that Date time is also there in back up file name.

Answer (score 1):

You define the SQL command to execute, and then instantiate a `SqlCommand`. Since the SQL statement isn't expected to return any data (a result set etc.), use `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
string Sql = "BACKUP DATABASE " + metroComboBox1.Text + " TO DISK = '" + metroTextBox4.Text + "\\" + metroComboBox1.Text + "-" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".bak'";

using(SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBS\\DB;Initial Catalog=" + metroTextBox1.Text + ";Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand cmdBackup = new SqlCommand(Sql, CON))
{   
    // open connection, execute command, close connection
    CON.Open();
    cmdBackup.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CON.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The general code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = "BACKUP DATABASE...";
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```